# Calling specific Python Script from C# process

Tags: c#, python, file-io

I'm trying to call python scripts from c#, so far so good. But when I try to call this specific script it is not workin.  This is what I'm doing in C#:

```
// Use ProcessStartInfo class
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "C:\\Python27\\python.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "pyScript.py";

// Start the process with the info we specified.
// Call WaitForExit and then the using statement will close.
using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
{
    StreamReader output_sr = exeProcess.StandardOutput;
    StreamReader error_sr = exeProcess.StandardError;
    String output = output_sr.ReadToEnd();
    String error = error_sr.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(output);
    Console.WriteLine(error);
    exeProcess.WaitForExit();
}
```

My pyScript.py file is the following:

```
with open ('test.txt','w') as f:
    for i in range(0x34):
        f.write('1')
f.close()
```

So basically what I spect is to create a file named 'test.txt' containing:

```
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

Also I'm not getting any error, and if I run it from console it works, even if I double click my python script it works. This is really weird and I don't have a clue why when I call if from c# the file is not being generated.

Comment: Just curious, is there any reason you're not using IronPython?

Comment: Yes, this is a basic example but my project is to call a huge already developed Python set of instructions that interacts with USB communication, Using IronPython will lead me to more compatibility issues and more work than just simply executing the scripts as a process in c#.

Comment: Really? I was under the assumption IronPython had pretty good compatibility to regular Python. My apologies. I've got nothing to go on right now. Sorry :(

Comment: I'm not that familiar with IronPython, perhaps it may be a better option to go. I will try to have both, but still I would like to get to the bottom of this particular issue. :)

Comment: Isn't it due to the application execution path ? Did you try absolute path ? do you copy your "pyscript.py" in your application directory during compilation ?

Answer (score 1):

Your 'test.txt' file is created in your **Debug** folder. Or simply where your C# executable is called from. Thus, it is working but you are looking wrong place.